# Arduino IDE Ubuntu ports greyed out (no serial port installed)

Tags: serial-port, arduino-ide

I want to run Arduino IDE on a Ubuntu machine that has no serial ports. I'm only going to be using it for OTA but the IDE port option is greyed out. I've tried installing tty0tty but that didn't help. I can set up two minicom serial sessions and chat between them on the tnt0 and tnt1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Arduino IDE as root? See [this SuperUser query](https://superuser.com/questions/1341671/linux-virtual-tty/1341748#1341748) for more details about the potential permissions issue.

Also, verify that your user is in the dialout group. This is a requirement for the ports to be accessible in Arduino.

From the [Arduino IDE docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting):

> On Linux, the Uno and Mega 2560 show up as devices of the form /dev/ttyACM0. These are not supported by the standard version of the RXTX library that the Arduino software uses for serial communication. The Arduino software download for Linux includes a version of the RXTX library patched to also search for these /dev/ttyACM* devices. There's also an Ubuntu package (for 11.04) which includes support for these devices. If, however, you're using the RXTX package from your distribution, you may need to symlink from /dev/ttyACM0 to /dev/ttyUSB0 (for example) so that the serial port appears in the Arduino software.
>   Run:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G tty yourUserName
> sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName
> ```